# How to set gradiant background for expander control wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am using expander control to create a user control. I want to set gradient background for the expander control. How to set gradient background for expander control?

Comment: you should show some code to get answer here.

Comment: Try this links 1)   http://prntscr.com/aqtq5g and 2)youtube.com/watch?v=TZMUF6KYW18

Answer (score 0):

Refer this :- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/wpf-lineargradientbrush-using-xaml/

```
<Border Margin="10,10,10,10" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8">
    <Border.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.504,1.5" StartPoint="0.504,0.03">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFC934" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.567"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.Background>

    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Width="Auto" Height="235" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">

            <StackPanel Margin="15,20,15,20">
                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="4" Width="108" Height="88">
                    <Image Source="cat.jpg" Height="80" Width="100" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Margin="0,20,0,20">
                <Label Content="Purushottam Rathore" FontSize="15" Foreground="Navy" />
                <Label Content="India" FontSize="15" Foreground="Navy"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Border>
```